# Programs still opening websites through Google Chrome, despite its removal

Tags: windows, google-chrome, hijack

Even after I've uninstalled Google Chrome, when other programs want to open a website (e.g.: Yahoo! Messenger getting a profile) they will still attempt to do so through Chrome, and fail looking for it.

I've read all the advice on how to make Firefox or IE for Windows 7 the default browser.

I don't think Google would do this sort of "hijack the default browser" thing and I'm convinced it must be a trojan or virus or even a registry hack.

If so, any ideas on how I would go about fixing this without purchasing every virus/trojan program until it *was* removed? That method could be an expensive fix.

Comment: Now that Google Chrome is uninstalled, you should make sure that one of your other browsers has been made the Default Browser.

Answer (score 1):

**Setting default browser manually**

You can manually set the default browser by selecting it as the the default program for individual file types and protocols, as follows:

- Windows XP and earlier: Open the Control Panel from the Windows Start menu.

  - In Windows 2000 and earlier, or if Windows XP is using the `Control Panel "Classic View"`: Click on `"Folder Options -> File Types`".
  - In Windows XP, if using the Control Panel "`Category View`": Click on "`Performance and Maintenance`". Then, click on "`File Types`" in the left column under the heading "See Also".
- Windows 7 and Vista: Click the Start button, open "`Default Programs`" and then click "`Associate a file type or protocol with a program`".

<sub><sup>[Source of above](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Setting_Your_Default_Browser#Force_Firefox_to_make_itself_the_default) and additional info</sup></sub>

Comment: Thank you Nifle Im a Windows 7 Home Premium box and so far your solution has worked for me. I like  Google Chrome just I like Firefox as my default browser.